# How do you conduct an outer join in typeorm?

Tags: typeorm

I am using typeorm in a project and want to conduct a left outer join. After going through their docs there is no mention of this at all and i am not convinced that left join will do what i need it to do. Is there a way to conduct an outer join in typeorm?

Just to share, this is the query i am trying to convert to typeorm:

```
    SELECT bsm."bId"
FROM (
    SELECT bs."id" "statusId", bs.label label, bs_mapping."bId" "bId"
    FROM bs_mapping
    LEFT JOIN bs
    ON bs.id = bs_mapping."binStatusId"
) bsm
LEFT OUTER JOIN tt_bs
ON tt_bs."statusId" = bsm."statusId"
WHERE ((bsm.label = 'inactive' OR bsm.label = 'block') AND
    tt_bs."ttId" IS NULL')
GROUP by bsm."bId"
```